# Proper escaping of LIKE queries with Doctrine querybuilder

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, sql-like

I'm trying to make a LIKE query with Doctrine QueryBuilder. I read on various other questions and articles that I have to proper escape this type of query, but I don't understand if Doctrine does it itself or not. Taking this data as an example:

```
my_column
ABC
ABCD
A%BCD
```

And the following input data

```
ABC
ABCD
A
A%
```

I expect these results:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column LIKE "%ABC%" => ABC, ABCD
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column LIKE "%ABCD%" => ABCD
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column LIKE "%A%" => ABC, ABCD, A, A%
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column LIKE "%A%%" => A%
```

My question relates the latest query (and input data). How should I proper escape that query? Is `'%' . addcslashes($input, '%_') . '%'` enough?

I prepared this SQL Fiddle if it can help: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35bc8/9

Comment: Just use parameters and you will be fine.  Apply the % signs to your data. 'SELECT ... LIKE ?' setParameter(0,'%' . 'ABC' . '%')

Comment: According to the gist https://gist.github.com/johnkary/9770413 I should escape myself the input data. Using setParameter as you suggested return incorrect results (ABC, ABCD, A, A%)

Comment: I'm not sure of the context of the gist you linked.  There is a greate deal of misinformation out there on DQL.  Perhaps the manual might help: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers (search for LIKE for an example).   If you are getting unexpected results then you might take a closer look at the actual query.  Perhaps update your question with the real code.  But I am 100% confident that you don't need to explicitly escape your data when using paramertized statements.

Comment: Paramertized statements don't need to be explicitly escaped for characters like quotes or backslashes, but LIKE statement apparently doesn't escape properly characters like % or _ leading to a SQL query like the last one I wrote in the fiddle. To treat that characters as literals manual escaping must be done, as found out in the linked gist. The only remaining question is why the escape character is escaped itself.

Comment: Regardless of what the final answer is here, I feel I should point out that queries containing `LIKE '%...%'` are really *really* bad for performance. You're basically telling the DB to load every single record and parse them all individually to search for your string, and then throw away the ones that don't match. If your database has even a moderate number of records, then that kind of query is going to run as slow as molasses. And don't even think about doing joins. There are good ways of doing complex searches if you need them. `LIKE %...%` is not one of those ways.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, in my case I have around 200-300 records so I don't think the query will be so slow. For sure if the amount grows things change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As found out with [this](https://gist.github.com/johnkary/9770413) gist by John Kary, Doctrine doesn't escape `LIKE` query statements. More specifically, it escapes the parameters using prepared statements (characters like backslashes or quotes are escaped properly) but characters like `%` or `_` which are part of the syntax of a `LIKE` statement are not escaped and the input is not sanitized. The gist linked below provides a nice way to solve this issue, tested with Symfony 2.6 and Doctrine 2.5 it works perfectly. Just to be sure that the gist won't be deleted, I copy here the code:

```
<?php
namespace Foo;

/**
 * Methods for safe LIKE querying.
 */
trait LikeQueryHelpers
{
    /**
     * Format a value that can be used as a parameter for a DQL LIKE search.
     *
     * $qb->where("u.name LIKE (:name) ESCAPE '!'")
     *    ->setParameter('name', $this->makeLikeParam('john'))
     *
     * NOTE: You MUST manually specify the `ESCAPE '!'` in your DQL query, AND the
     * ! character MUST be wrapped in single quotes, else the Doctrine DQL
     * parser will throw an error:
     *
     * [Syntax Error] line 0, col 127: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_STRING, got '"'
     *
     * Using the $pattern argument you can change the LIKE pattern your query
     * matches again. Default is "%search%". Remember that "%%" in a sprintf
     * pattern is an escaped "%".
     *
     * Common usage:
     *
     * ->makeLikeParam('foo')         == "%foo%"
     * ->makeLikeParam('foo', '%s%%') == "foo%"
     * ->makeLikeParam('foo', '%s_')  == "foo_"
     * ->makeLikeParam('foo', '%%%s') == "%foo"
     * ->makeLikeParam('foo', '_%s')  == "_foo"
     *
     * Escapes LIKE wildcards using '!' character:
     *
     * ->makeLikeParam('foo_bar') == "%foo!_bar%"
     *
     * @param string $search        Text to search for LIKE
     * @param string $pattern       sprintf-compatible substitution pattern
     * @return string
     */
    protected function makeLikeParam($search, $pattern = '%%%s%%')
    {
        /**
         * Function defined in-line so it doesn't show up for type-hinting on
         * classes that implement this trait.
         *
         * Makes a string safe for use in an SQL LIKE search query by escaping all
         * special characters with special meaning when used in a LIKE query.
         *
         * Uses ! character as default escape character because \ character in
         * Doctrine/DQL had trouble accepting it as a single \ and instead kept
         * trying to escape it as "\\". Resulted in DQL parse errors about "Escape
         * character must be 1 character"
         *
         * % = match 0 or more characters
         * _ = match 1 character
         *
         * Examples:
         *      gloves_pink   becomes  gloves!_pink
         *      gloves%pink   becomes  gloves!%pink
         *      glo_ves%pink  becomes  glo!_ves!%pink
         *
         * @param string $search
         * @return string
         */
        $sanitizeLikeValue = function ($search) {
            $escapeChar = '!';
            $escape = [
                '\\' . $escapeChar, // Must escape the escape-character for regex
                '\%',
                '\_',
            ];
            $pattern = sprintf('/([%s])/', implode('', $escape));
            return preg_replace($pattern, $escapeChar . '$0', $search);
        };
        return sprintf($pattern, $sanitizeLikeValue($search));
    }
}
```

And it's used like this example:

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Foo\LikeQueryHelpers;

class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    use LikeQueryHelpers;
    /**
     * Find Product entities containing searched terms
     *
     * @param string $term
     * @return Product[]
     */
    public function findInSearchableFields($term)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->where("p.title LIKE :title ESCAPE '!'")
            ->setParameter('title', $this->makeLikeParam($term))
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems unnecessary. You don't need to escape arguments when you are using prepared statements. See: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/security.html#right-prepared-statements

Comment: Quoting from the answer, Doctrine indeed escape input parameters but not the syntax of the LIKE SQL statement, so if you put a quote inside the value of the argument it will be escaped, but if you put a % sign it won't and this will open your application to security issues

Comment: Well % is not escaped because having % in argument is NOT a security risk as such it won't cause problems like SQL injections. It is up to you if you want to use % as a literal or wildcard. So it is a design decision on your part. Whether it is a security problem or not is up to your design.

Comment: Actually not escaping % in a LIKE statement IS a security issue because it could cause performance issues of your application and thus is a Denial of Service vector as explained here: https://githubengineering.com/like-injection/

Comment: Like I said, this depends on your design. I may want to make a search and use % in it by default already with a limit clause. It may be perfectly acceptable to use. I know several services which allow usage of wildcards. If what you said was true, and it was a security risk in 100% of the cases it would have been escaped by default.

Comment: I'm not a security expert so I can't comment further, what I know is that internet is full of articles about SQL Wildcard Attacks which is the case here